# Centos VM virtualbox installation, stuck on the language selction screen

Tags: installation, centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have created a CentOS VM on VirtualBox. I have used an ISO image to boot it.
but at the language selction screen, after selection my language the "continue" button at the bottom right does not click to let me move to the next screen and continue setup.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck in the process.
[image: Language seection screen]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the virtualbox tag states: Only programming-related questions are on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I had to right-click on the continue button to make it work. I was left-clicking the whole time.

I discovered it all by mistake.

Thanks.